# Application doing too much work on main thread(Firebase and OnLongClickListener)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get my app to send information to firebase, at first go it allows it to send the information to firebase, but on the second go it shows a message of 
"Skipped n# frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." and "Background concurrent copying GC freed 185001(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 12MB/18MB...".

The main function of this is to send information about a game if the button for it has been click for long(OnLongClickListener).

The java file for this function is this:

**HomePageActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Firebase FavDBRef;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private Button LeagueButton, OWButton, CSGOButton, DOTAButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        setupUIViews();
        gameButtons();

    }

    public void setupUIViews(){
        LeagueButton = findViewById(R.id.leagueButton);
        OWButton = findViewById(R.id.owButton);
        CSGOButton = findViewById(R.id.csgoButton);
        DOTAButton = findViewById(R.id.dotaButton);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    }

    public void gameButtons(){

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        FavDBRef = new Firebase("https://mwt-esportsinfo-userfav.firebaseio.com/" + firebaseUser.getUid()).child("FavEsport");

        LeagueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, LeagueOfLegends.class));
            }
        });

        LeagueButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                FavDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String FavEsport = "League of Legends";
                        String FavEsportDev = "Riot Games";
                        String FavEsportRel = "27 October 2009";
                        String FavEsportGenre = "Multiplayer Online Battle Arena";
                        String FavEsportImg = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/8/86/League_of_legends_logo_transparent.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20131023175853";

                        UserFavESport userFavESport = new UserFavESport(FavEsport, FavEsportDev, FavEsportRel, FavEsportGenre, FavEsportImg);

                        FavDBRef.setValue(userFavESport);

                        Toast.makeText(HomePageActivity.this, FavEsport + " has been added as Favourite eSport", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });

        OWButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                FavDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String FavEsport = "Overwatch";
                        String FavEsportDev = "Blizzard Entertainment";
                        String FavEsportRel = "24 May 2016";
                        String FavEsportGenre = "First-Person Shooter";
                        String FavEsportImg = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dbxfanon/images/8/84/Overwatch_logo_by_feeerieke-da4xuzp.png/revision/latest?cb=20170316184119";

                        UserFavESport userFavESport = new UserFavESport(FavEsport, FavEsportDev, FavEsportRel, FavEsportGenre, FavEsportImg);

                        FavDBRef.setValue(userFavESport);

                        Toast.makeText(HomePageActivity.this, FavEsport + " has been added as Favourite eSport", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });

        CSGOButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                FavDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String FavEsport = "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive";
                        String FavEsportDev = "Valve Corporation";
                        String FavEsportRel = "21 August 2012";
                        String FavEsportGenre = "First-Person Shooter";
                        String FavEsportImg = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/c/c8/CSGO.png/revision/latest?cb=20150828062634";

                        UserFavESport userFavESport = new UserFavESport(FavEsport, FavEsportDev, FavEsportRel, FavEsportGenre, FavEsportImg);

                        FavDBRef.setValue(userFavESport);

                        Toast.makeText(HomePageActivity.this, FavEsport + " has been added as Favourite eSport", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });

        DOTAButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                FavDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String FavEsport = "DOTA 2";
                        String FavEsportDev = "Valve Corporation";
                        String FavEsportRel = "9 July 2013";
                        String FavEsportGenre = "Multiplayer Online Battle Arena";
                        String FavEsportImg = "http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/Kravlenissen/Dota-2%284x3%291-1.png";

                        UserFavESport userFavESport = new UserFavESport(FavEsport, FavEsportDev, FavEsportRel, FavEsportGenre, FavEsportImg);

                        FavDBRef.setValue(userFavESport);

                        Toast.makeText(HomePageActivity.this, FavEsport + " has been added as Favourite eSport", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.profileMenu){
            startActivity(new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logoutMenu){
            Logout();
        }
        else{
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void Logout(){
        firebaseAuth.signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(HomePageActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

and for retrieving those information.

**UserFavESport.java**

```
public class UserFavESport {
    String favEsports, favEsportsDev, favEsportsRel, favEsportsGenre, favEsportsImg ;

    public UserFavESport(){

    }

    public UserFavESport(String favEsports, String favEsportsDev, String favEsportsRel, String favEsportsGenre, String favEsportsImg) {
        this.favEsports = favEsports;
        this.favEsportsDev = favEsportsDev;
        this.favEsportsRel = favEsportsRel;
        this.favEsportsGenre = favEsportsGenre;
        this.favEsportsImg = favEsportsImg;
    }

    public String getFavEsports() {
        return favEsports;
    }

    public void setFavEsports(String favEsports) {
        this.favEsports = favEsports;
    }

    public String getFavEsportsDev() {
        return favEsportsDev;
    }

    public void setFavEsportsDev(String favEsportsDev) {
        this.favEsportsDev = favEsportsDev;
    }

    public String getFavEsportsRel() {
        return favEsportsRel;
    }

    public void setFavEsportsRel(String favEsportsRel) {
        this.favEsportsRel = favEsportsRel;
    }

    public String getFavEsportsGenre() {
        return favEsportsGenre;
    }

    public void setFavEsportsGenre(String favEsportsGenre) {
        this.favEsportsGenre = favEsportsGenre;
    }

    public String getFavEsportsImg() {
        return favEsportsImg;
    }

    public void setFavEsportsImg(String favEsportsImg) {
        this.favEsportsImg = favEsportsImg;
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread" tells that you are doing long operations on your main thread. We should always avoid doing long operations on main thread and instead, do it on background threads. All your code apart from showing toast in the long click listener of the button should go on a new thread instead of main thread. Just create a new thread inside click listener method and delegate this work to the new thread.

You can use Thread and Runnable for processing data out of main Thread or use Async task if you want to communicate result back to UI thread.

Comment: would you be able to help me start it off?

Comment: Sure @JonSally. You can use simple below code to start new thread :-Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 //your code
                        }
            }
        };
 
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();